# How to join ggplot points on google map in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I know how to join points using ggplot():

```
dd <- data.frame(a=c(21.01223,18.45598,17.04542,19.44312),b=c(52.22968,51.75925,50.12482, 51.78745),
                 g=rep(1:2,2))

library(ggplot)

ggplot(data=dd,aes(x=a,y=b,group=g)) +
  geom_point(col=rep(c("darkred","black"),each=2),size=5)+
  geom_line(linetype=3)
```

but how to join this points on google map ?
I can only draw the points, but how to join them ?

```
library(ggmap)
qmap('Poland',zoom=6) + 
geom_point(data=dd,aes(x=a,y=b),col=rep(c("darkred","black"),each=2),size=5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To join the points you can pass the data into the `geom_line()` geom as well.

```
library(ggmap)
myMap <- get_map("Poland", zoom = 6)

ggmap(myMap) + 
  geom_point(data=dd, aes(x=a,y=b), col=rep(c("darkred","black"), each=2), size=5) +
  geom_line(data=dd, aes(x=a, y=b, group = g))
```

[image]

Comment: thx, perfect solution ! :) additionally can you advise how to define "alpha" in geom_point for each group ? For example for group = 1 I want alpha = 0.2 and for group = 2 I want alpha = 1...

Comment: @faryzeusz Try adding a column to your data that satisfies your alpha criteria, and use that column as the alpha value?